# Create a matrix of pairwise comparisons between columns

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a matrix showing the number of row-wise differences for each pairwise comparison of columns. This is what I'm starting with:

```
     Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
Att1    A    A    B
Att2    A    C    C
Att3    B    B    D
```

This is what I want to end up with:

```
      Ind1  Ind2  Ind3
Ind1            
Ind2    1       
Ind3    3     2
```

How can I do this in Python or R?

Comment: In the future, it's probably better to pick a single language tag at a time. Otherwise you get answers in two language without anyone telling you which is which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `adist` like below

```
> adist(sapply(df, toString))
     Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
Ind1    0    1    3
Ind2    1    0    2
Ind3    3    2    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "     Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
Att1    A    A    B
Att2    A    C    C
Att3    B    B    D")

v <- apply(combn(1:ncol(df), 2), 2, function(k) sum(df[, k[1]] != df[, k[2]]))
M <- matrix(0, nrow = ncol(df), ncol = ncol(df))
M[lower.tri(M)] <- v
M

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    3    2    0
```

Comment: Note that `combn(1:ncol(df),2)==combn(ncol(df),2)`. Didn't think about the `lower.tri` trick : nice!

Comment: Oh, yes @Waldi. OP can you use both versions. Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
arr = df.values.T
arr = np.sum(arr[:, None] != arr, axis = -1)
mask = np.triu(np.ones(arr.shape)) == 0
arr = np.where(mask, arr, np.nan)

>>> pd.DataFrame(data = arr, index = df.columns, columns = df.columns)
      Ind1  Ind2  Ind3
Ind1   NaN   NaN   NaN
Ind2   1.0   NaN   NaN
Ind3   3.0   2.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R approach:

```
x <- combn(df, 2, function(x)sum(do.call("!=", x)))

attributes(x) <- list(Labels = names(df), Size = ncol(df), class = "dist")

x
     Ind1 Ind2
Ind2    1     
Ind3    3    2
```

If you want, you could do:

```
as.matrix(x)
     Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
Ind1    0    1    3
Ind2    1    0    2
Ind3    3    2    0
```

Comment: For the pytthon, you could do: `pd.DataFrame((df.values.T != df.values.T[:, None]).sum(2), columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

**1) sapply** Perform a double `sapply` over the indicated function.  We can optionally use as.dist on this and similarly on the other alternatives shown later but won't repeat it for each one.

```
nc <- ncol(m)
res <- sapply(1:nc, function(i) sapply(1:nc, function(j) sum(m[, i] != m[, j])))

res
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0    1    3
## [2,]    1    0    2
## [3,]    3    2    0
```

or

```
as.dist(res)
##   1 2
## 2 1  
## 3 3 2
```

**2) List Comprehension** Using the eList package we could generate it like this:

```
library(eList)

nc <- ncol(m)
Mat(for(i in 1:nc) for(j in 1:nc) sum(m[, i] != m[, j]))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0    1    3
## [2,]    1    0    2
## [3,]    3    2    0
```

**3) outer** We can use `outer` like this:

```
f <- function(i, j) sum(m[, i] != m[, j])
outer(1:nc, 1:nc, Vectorize(f))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0    1    3
## [2,]    1    0    2
## [3,]    3    2    0
```

### Note

```
m <- structure(c("A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "D"), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("Att1", "Att2", "Att3"), c("Ind1", "Ind2", 
"Ind3")))
```